# DTMF sounds for custom Dialer iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am trying to add dtmf sounds to my custom dialer pad.
I managed reproducing a sound for each number on touch down. Now I am trying to achieve the natural phone behaviour for when the person who is dialing does a "longpress" on a number.
The problem is that the sound ends. How could I make it lasting as long as the touch ends?
In my code for now I am trying to add a long sound even if I am using the touch down event, just to test if it works. If it does I will add the gesture recognizer for long press.

Here is my code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
 //SystemSoundID toneSSIDs[12];
    AVAudioPlayer *toneSSIDs[12];
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        for(int count = 0; count < 12; count++){
           NSString *toneFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dtmf-%d", count];

            NSURL *toneURLRef = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:toneFilename
                                                        withExtension:@"mp3"];

            player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:toneURLRef error:NULL ];
            player.volume = 0.4f;

            toneSSIDs[count] = player;
        }
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)playSoundForKey:(int)key {
    _sound = toneSSIDs[key];
    _sound.delegate = self;
    _sound.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [_sound prepareToPlay];
    [_sound play];
}

- (IBAction)touchNum:(id)sender {
  [self playSoundForKey:[sender tag]];
}
```

I tried using both .wav and .mp3 sounds and also looping the sound but I get multiple sounds, not a long one as I need. Somebody help, please!

Comment: try setting it to loop infinitely, call `[_sound play]` on touchDown and call `[_sound stop]` on touchUp

Comment: It simply stops looping, but the loop is always the same..multiple sounds, not a long one :(

Comment: Can you extend the play length of the tone played, and then do what @SimonMcLoughlin suggested? For instance, if your current tone is :03, make a new one that is :30 and play/stop that on touch down/up. While this technically wouldn't solve the exact question you asked, it could possibly solve the issue of the sound cutting off (other than in a rare very very long press)

Comment: There should be a way to loop it in the right way avoiding to use a longer sound. We can't predict how long the user will keep a button pressed!